# Load runner throwing error -26628 Getting Forbidden error while replay of script for api through https

Tags: loadrunner

Recorded the script in load runner 12.02, While replaying the script, Getting Error -26628: HTTP Status-Code=403 (Forbidden) for one of the Rest API.URL Credentials given are also correct.Can you please suggest how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely missing a header credential.   Look at the authentication model used for the server under test.  Better than 50% odds you will needs to use a web_add_auto_header() to include several base64 encoded values in the header related to your user credentials for access to the server under test

Well, that or you have missed a dynamic element related to state or session and when the unhandled identifier is encountered then the server cuts the session as invalid.